# Ubuntu from torrent links

Tags: downloads, versions, bittorrent

Is the Ubuntu which will be downloaded from the torrent link (given on this website) the full version that comes pre-installed on some laptops or will I have to pay some money to get it activated or for its key?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate of that, since it's also about versions, not just about if there is a cost.  Also because this question is looking for personal use, and you linked something that's looking for business use.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER let someone trick you into paying to get an activation key or "full version" of Ubuntu.  I don't know for sure which link you are referring to, and as this is a community site, anyone could potentially give you any link.  You can get the official Ubuntu releases for your computer at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

As far as which version you want...  most computers that do come with it pre-installed come with either the 14.04.3 LTS or the 15.10 (in most cases).  Mine came with it pre-installed and had an option between 14.04 LTS or 14.10 (it was before 15.10).  15.10 is the newest, but the LTS stands for "Long Term Support" and offers a longer term of official security and maintenance updates.

I hope that helped you figure out what you want!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am talking about this link : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads Here, under torrent downloads. Are they full versions?

Comment: That is from the official Ubuntu site, so I would say to trust it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is completely free. There is no "demo" version or "product key". It's just free. The torrent links are the real deal, just make sure to use the download link from Ubuntu's own website.